# How to define custom macros in MathJax

Tags: macros, latex, mathjax

I'm trying to define custom macros used in LaTeX files in MathJax.

Can define simple macros (single parameter) without any issue such as;

```
\newcommand{\braket}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
```

as

```
Macros: {
    braket: ['{\\langle #1 \\rangle}', 1]
}
```

But struggle with complicated ones;

```
\newcommand{\Abs}[2][]{\left\lvert#2\right\rvert_{\text{#1}}}
```

trying to define it like;

```
Macros: {
    Abs: ['{\\left\\lvert#2\\rvert_{\\text{#1}}}', 2]
}
```

but no luck.

This is how it is used in LaTeX file

```
\begin{align}\nonumber
    p_e = \Abs{\braket{e|\psi(t)}}^2 = \sin^2\Omega t\, .
\end{align}
```

Not sure where I did wrong.

I'm not a LaTeX expert, but just a developer trying to display LaTeX files on a web app (for Quantum Physics community), so I would greatly appreciate your help. thanks.

*P.S this question was asked and closed on SE they redirected me to SO.*

Comment: What kind of problems are you seeing? This seems to work, see http://codepen.io/pkra/pen/AqdGs. (IIRC, the [Braket package](http://ctan.org/pkg/braket) is more complicated though.)

Comment: @Peter Krautzberger I want to define that macro in Mathjax settings instead of adding "\newcommand{\Abs}.." to every single HTML file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've updated [the codepen from my comment](http://codepen.io/pkra/pen/AqdGs).

Primarliy, you forgot a `\\right`; I also modified your macro definition so that it has an optional parameter. In other words, something along the lines of:

```
Macros: {
    braket: ['{\\langle #1 \\rangle}', 1],
   Abs: ['\\left\\lvert #2 \\right\\rvert_{\\text{#1}}', 2, ""]
}},
```

Comment: thanks Peter it works with the third empty parameter in the array. I'm curious where you got that information from, I couldnt manage to find it on MathJax docs.

Comment: I admit I had to dive into the code of a few TeX extensions. I filed an issue on our docs https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/issues/73