# How to define custom macro for mathjax expression inside asciidoc?

Tags: mathjax, asciidoc

I have some mathematical expression that I would like to reuse in my asciidoc document:

```
:stem: latexmath

[latexmath]
++++        
E^{\unicode{x2307}\unicode{x2307}\unicode{x2307}}       
++++
```

In order to get equations that are easier to read I would like to use a shortcut, e.g.

```
:stem: latexmath

[latexmath]
++++        
E^{\myCustomSymbol}       
++++
```

or

```
:stem: latexmath

[latexmath]
++++        
E^{include::myCustomSymbol.ad}       
++++
```

=> How can I use asciidoc imports inside mathematical expressions or

=> How can I define mathjax macros inside asciidoc (is it possible to adapt the mathjax configuration with some special commands) ?

Related questions:

- [how to define own asciidoc macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330192/how-to-define-own-asciidoc-macro)
- [How to define custom macros in MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628668/how-to-define-custom-macros-in-mathjax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
:stem: latexmath

[latexmath]
++++        
\newcommand{\myCustomSymbol}{{\unicode{x2307}\unicode{x2307}\unicode{x2307}}}
E^{\myCustomSymbol}       
++++

[latexmath]
++++
E^{\myCustomSymbol}       
++++
```

You only need to define the symbol once, then can use it from then on.

Comment: Note that this indeed works fine with asciidoctor, but not asciidoctor-pdf (with asciidoctor-mathematical). I couldn't find any way to make it also work for the latter so far, unfortunately.