# Custom macro in MathJax with optional parameters

Tags: latex, mathjax

I am trying to implement the partialderivative macro from the Physics package in MathJax. Based on the response at [How to define custom macros in MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628668/how-to-define-custom-macros-in-mathjax), I defined `pdv: ["{\\frac{\\partial^{#1}{ #2 }}{\\partial{ #3 }^{#1}}}", 3,""],` so that `\pdv[2]{u}{x}` gives the second partial derivative of `u` with respect to `y`. However, I am not sure on how to define the macro to get mixed partial derivatives; e.g. in LaTeX `\pdv[2]{u}{x}{y}` gives the mixed partial derivative of `u` with respect to `x` and `y`. Any help to implement this is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Add a snippet so people can help you fix the code.

Comment: I can get mixed partial derivatives by defining a different macro `mpdv: ["{\\frac{\\partial^{#1}{ #2 }}{\\partial{ #3 }\\partial{#4}}}", 4,""]`, but in this case the 4-th parameter is no longer optional (and does not reduce in any case to the desired form). I would prefer not to have to redo my documents to use a different macro for mixed partials.  I am not sure if there is a way to use macro "overloading", where a different form is called depending on the number of arguments.

Comment: It's not possible in this simple format. You'd have to write an extension so that you can write a custom function around this. But that's a question that doesn't fit on SO. There's the documentation https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/extension-writing.html and you can ask on the MathJax User Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users.